# EF Core - Best way to implement business logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a REST API in .NET CORE and Entity Framework. The thing is i want to make it as clean and re-usable as possible.

I though that the *Repository Pattern* (with UoW, services etc) was a go-to architecture but i read that it was useless to implement Repositories with EF Core because it is what DbContext does already.

**My question is** : Where should i wrote all of my business / validation logic ?

I tried to create one *EntityContext* (that inherit *DbContext*) per *Entity*, and make them containing the methods needed for their *entity*, but it looks like this is not the correct way to do it.

I read that everything can be put directly on the *Entity* classes, but it looks weird to me (maybe because i'm used to *Repository Pattern*).

Let's say i have an *Employee* class :

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeId = new Guid();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }

    public string? CurrentAddress { get; set; }

    public string PermanentAddress { get; set; }

    public string? City { get; set; }

    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    public string? PINCode { get; set; }
}
```

And that i want to implement a method called **GetAllWithPINCode** that returns all *Employees* that have a *PINCode*.

Is there **good practices** that define where to write this method ?
Should it be directly in the controller, in the *Entity* class or in an intermediate layer ?

Comment: *it was useless to implement Repositories with EF Core because it is what DbContext does already* That's just disputable. Just make your repositories over EF and you are fine. That's perfectly fine approach.

Comment: I recommend Swagger with all my API development. It's so much easier to manage and test

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine to create a `Repositories` project, containing repository classes implementing the repository pattern, and referencing `EF Core` in the repositories, e.g.:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public EmployeeRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    } 

    public Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetAllWithPinCodeAsync()
    {
        return _context.Employees
                       .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PINCode))
                       .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// assume employeeRepository of type EmployeeRepository instantiated

var employeesWithPins = await employeeRepository.GetAllWithPinCodeAsync();
```

Comment: I completely agree. I personally think this is the cleanest way to do database interactions. This way you can extend/ overwrite functions you slightly want to change. I can also really recommend using a generic/ base repository with basic CRUD functionality.

Comment: Completely disagree and highly not recommend to use Generic repositories. DbSet is already generic repository.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely shouldn't in Entity Class or Controller. In SOLID-Single responsibility principle says every class, method etc. has to one responsibility.So your method should be in **Repository or Business Service**.

You should ask yourself this question. If I need this method elsewhere in the project, how can I reference the same method/service without repeating the code? It wouldn't be good practice to reference controllers and entity classes if you did as you asked.